# How to Detect Device Type without Spring-Mobile

Tags: java, spring-boot, mobile, device-detection, spring-mobile

I know there are multiple questions asked like that but I have tried all of their solutions and none of them worked for me.
Before now, we were using `Spring-Mobile` for detection of Device that is requesting from the browser. But because its support is no longer available, we need to switch to a different strategy.

I have seen different solutions using `HttpServletRequest` to detect the device type (if it is a mobile, Tablet or Desktop) from its `Header` through `User-Agent`. Following is the code I have used to detect Mobile device using this approach:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
System.out.println("User-Agent => " + userAgent.contains("Mobi")); //prints false
```

I have tried this by sending request from browser through inspect element and also by using original Mobile Device but in both cases, it return `false`.

## Mobileesp.org:

I also saw a solution that used [mobileesp.org](https://github.com/ahand/mobileesp) but I am not quite sure If I am implementing it correctly in my application or not. I only copied its folder of `Java` and pasted in my application. There, I called its constructor and tried to detect mobile devices but all the methods returned `false` on mobile detection. Again, I tested that on real device and on browser as well. Following is my code:

```
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent"); // request => HttpServletRequest (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
        UAgentInfo user = new UAgentInfo(userAgent, "");

        // All of Below methods are returning False
        System.out.println(user.detectAndroidPhone());
        System.out.println(user.isAndroidPhone);
        System.out.println(user.isIphone);
        System.out.println(user.isMobilePhone);
        System.out.println(user.detectAndroid());
        System.out.println(user.detectSmartphone());
        System.out.println(user.detectAndroidTablet());
        System.out.println(user.detectMobileQuick());
        System.out.println(user.detectMobileLong());
        System.out.println(user.isAndroid);
```

Your help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Yusufgndz that's the problem. It is not any longer supported By Spring says the official documentation https://spring.io/projects/spring-mobile. We are already using this but now, it is not working.